# esp-idf - mqtt ssl example certificate error

Tags: mqtt, esp32, tls

I'm having some trouble with mqtt ssl example on esp-idf ESP32.

Example: [mqtt_ssl](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/mqtt/ssl)

If I test it with the default broker "mqtts://mqtt.eclipse.org:8883" and default certificate "mqtt_eclipse_org.pem"
It works correctly.

If I change the broker with mqtts://test.mosquitto.org:8883
( https://test.mosquitto.org/ ) and change the certificate using (mosquitto.org.crt (PEM format), it fails and gave me TLS errors:

```
mbedtls:ssl_tls.c:5757 x509_verify_cert() returned -9984 (-0x2700)

esp-tls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned .0x2700
     esp-tls: Failed to verify peer certificate!
     failed to verify peer certificate
     verification info: ! the certificate is not correctly signed by the trusted CA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How/where did you get the certificate? You are supposed to provide the root certificate for the one used by the server you connect to.

Comment: I got it from https://test.mosquitto.org/ 
There was an error on the example config.
But I got this error now:

"verification info:   ! The certificate is signed with an unacceptable key (eg bad curve, RSA too short)."

Comment: `openssl x509 -in mosquitto.org.crt -text -noout` shows RSA 1024, while
`openssl x509 -in mqtt_eclipse_org.pem -text -noout` shows RSA 2048.
So you need to find out whether the esp-idf supports certificates with 1024-bit RSA public keys.

Comment: Need to change this :

rsa_min_bitlen in
mbedtls_x509_crt_profile_default in x509_crt.c line 110 to 1024 and enabled
#define MBEDTLS_TLS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_SHA1_IN_CERTIFICATES
in mbedtls/config.h line 3273.

But this is not a good idea.
Now I'm wondering why mosquitto has so weak certificate..